# Hair Dynamics not working on mesh from Daz Bridge

Tags: particles, hair

An interesting problem trying to use Blender particle hair with Daz models via the Daz Blender bridge (because Daz don't offer strand/particle hair with physics to the masses).  Duplicated some mesh from the head to create a cap and added particle hair with dynamics.  Nothings happens when you simulate. To debug I have eliminated all other assets from the file and also added a new UV sphere.  With the same setup, hair dynamics on UV sphere works fine but hair on cap does not.  Can anyone tell me why this is.  File uploaded if you want to try it.  Issue is the same in 2.83 and 2.92.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry file was too large to load to Blender Exchange and in the process of trying to reduce the size I changed the number of hairs from 1000 to 100 and after that it worked.  Must be a bug of some kind but I seem to have a work around. Trying that back in the main file now.

Comment: OK got a smaller version of the blend file uploaded.  Workaround I stumbled on in the comment above did not work this time.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set the simulation end on the cap to 0. Set it to 250 and it works.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Rookie error...

Comment: no problem. we all began some time ago - although some people here forgot this ;) i make rookie mistakes all the time ;)